# NtQuerySystemInformation returns 24 (ERROR_BAD_LENGTH)

Tags: c, winapi, nt

Here is my function:

```
PVOID QuerySystemInformation(SYSTEMINFOCLASS SystemEnum) {
        DWORD MemorySize = NULL;
        NTSTATUS Status = NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemEnum, NULL, 0, &MemorySize);
        if (NT_SUCCESS(Status)) {
            PVOID Memory = PVOID(Allocate(MemorySize));
            if (Memory != ERROR) {
                Status = NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemEnum, Memory, MemorySize, &MemorySize);
                if (NT_SUCCESS(Status)) {
                    return Memory;
                }
                Free(Memory);
            }
        }
        return ERROR;
    }
```

I pass `SystemBasicInformation` to the function. After the first call to `NtQuerySystemInformation`, I get an error. The result of `RtlNtStatusToDosError(Status)` is `24 (ERROR_BAD_LENGTH)`. Where is the problem?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own post.

Comment: What makes that even worse is that you appear to have gotten multiple useful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`NtQuerySystemInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725506(v=vs.85).aspx) if *SystemInformationLength* too small for hold info return error `STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH`. (*`RtlNtStatusToDosError(STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)==ERROR_BAD_LENGTH`*)

need understand that some *SystemInformationClass* return well known **fixed** size data. as example *SystemBasicInformation*

so you need do next for this **fixed** size Information Class :

```
SYSTEM_BASIC_INFORMATION sbi;
NTSTATUS status = ZwQuerySystemInformation(SystemBasicInformation, &sbi, sizeof(sbi), 0);
if (0 <= status)
{
    // do something
}
```

but some Information Class return variable length data. required length is unknown at begin and `STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH` here absolute normal error (not fatal). the variable length Information Class you need always query **in loop** and check returned status for `STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH` as conditional continue loop:

```
do 
{
    ...
    status = ZwQuerySystemInformation(...);
    ...
} while (status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH);
```

why in loop ? because the required length can change after system return to you size of buffer required to receive the requested information and before you call `ZwQuerySystemInformation` again with this buffer size.

the bright example of this `SystemProcessInformation` which got information about all processes and threads running currently in system. after system return to you size of buffer required - new threads or processes can start in system - as result larger buffer can be need.

we can query this info in next way:

```
NTSTATUS QueryProcessInformation()
{
    NTSTATUS status;

    ULONG cb = 0x10000;

    do 
    {
        status = STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;

        if (void* buf = new BYTE[cb])
        {
            if (0 <= (status = ZwQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, buf, cb, &cb)))
            {
                union {
                    PVOID pv;
                    PBYTE pb;
                    PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION pspi;
                };

                pv = buf;

                ULONG NextEntryOffset = 0;

                do 
                {
                    pb += NextEntryOffset;

                    DbgPrint("%p %wZ\n", pspi->UniqueProcessId, &pspi->ImageName);

                } while (NextEntryOffset = pspi->NextEntryOffset);
            }

            delete [] buf;
        }

    } while (status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH);

    return status;
}
```

or alternatively we can use cumulative allocation in stack (this is only for user mode, where we have huge stack size)

```
NTSTATUS QueryProcessInformation2()
{
    NTSTATUS status;

    union {
        PVOID buf;
        PBYTE pb;
        PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION pspi;
    };

    ULONG cb = 0, rcb = 0x10000;

    volatile UCHAR guz;

    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);

    do 
    {
        if (cb < rcb)
        {
            cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
        }

        if (0 <= (status = ZwQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, buf, cb, &rcb)))
        {
            ULONG NextEntryOffset = 0;

            do 
            {
                pb += NextEntryOffset;

                DbgPrint("%p %wZ\n", pspi->UniqueProcessId, &pspi->ImageName);

            } while (NextEntryOffset = pspi->NextEntryOffset);
        }

    } while (status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH);

    return status;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is no problem - the error is to be expected for calls with a zero `SystemInformationLength` parameter.

MSDN says about [`NtQuerySystemInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724509(v=vs.85).aspx):

> ReturnLength [out, optional] - 4th parameter
>
> An optional pointer to a location where the function writes the actual size of the information requested. If that size is less than or equal to the SystemInformationLength parameter, the function copies the information into the SystemInformation buffer; **otherwise, it returns an NTSTATUS error code and returns in ReturnLength the size of buffer required to receive the requested information.**

So check if `DWORD MemorySize` does contain a non-zero size.

Comment: Oooh. Okay thank you so much! I'm so silly for not paying attention to the documentation!

Comment: Now in the same function, I am getting `0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x4865764A` After the call to Allocate() , anything obvious stating the reasoning behind this?

Comment: I could only guess because I don't know what allocator you are using and where exactly the error occurs. Can't you use a debugger?

Comment: `So check if DWORD MemorySize` - no. need check exactly returned status for determinate what todo.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove

```
if (NT_SUCCESS(Status)) {
```

And replace it with:

```
if(MemorySize){
```

Comment: this is error. all conditional `if` must be only based on return status